# init] in automatic reference counting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, initialization, alloc, automatic-ref-counting

I know that I am suppose to use:

```
ObjectClass *tmpObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];
realObject = tmpObject;
[tmpObject release]
```

to initialise `realObject` (where `realObject` is an object within a class)

But now with ARC mode, releasing is automatic, do i still need to use this technique?
Can I simply use `realObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];`?
If not is there any specific reason why it would leak?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Spencer said, if you compile with ARC enabled, you cannot call `release` at all.  It is an error to do so and the compiler takes care of it for you.

However:

```
ObjectClass *tmpObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];
realObject = tmpObject;
[tmpObject release]
```

The `tmpObject` in that case is entirely pointless for both ARC and manual retain-release.  And, in fact, in manual retain-release, the above code will immediately release the object allocated, causing it to be deallocated (unless `ObjectClass` internally does something odd) and `realObject` will be left with a dangling pointer.

I.e. that code, as written, will cause a crash the first time anyone tries to message `realObject`.

To clarify:

```
ObjectClass *tmpObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];
// tmpObject now contains a reference to an instance of ObjectClass; say, 0x12340
realObject = tmpObject;
// realObject now contains a reference to that same instance; realObject == 0x12340
[tmpObject release]
// this releases the object
// both tmpObject and realObject now reference a deallocated object; much hilarity ensues.
```

---

For ARC, you just do this:

```
realObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: I don't get the part about why that code doesn't work though. I just read sample code which had: 'SecondViewController *aSecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];' Isn't that the same thing? get temp object pointer and init what you want, then set a pointer from the real object to the initiated stuff. Finally release the temp object pointer.
[self setSecondViewController:aSecondView];
[aSecondView release];

Comment: In that case, `setSecondViewController:` will retain `aSecondView` (if the internal implementation details deem it necessary -- most likely it retains, it might do something else).

Answer (score 4):

If you are compiling with -fobjc-arc (ie, using ARC) then not only do you not need to call `release`, it is a compiler error if you do so. When using ARC, it is the job of the compiler to insert `retain` and `release` calls for you.

Comment: So which method of creating an object is correct (or better)? Should I change all my "realObject = [[ObjectClass alloc] init];"?

Comment: The object creation stays the same, IIRC.

Comment: Yes -- object creation stays the same, there just aren't any retains/releases in the code.  The problem, though, is that Tim's code is busted in the first place.